istio sample addon for prometheus and grafana not working for all workloads
in our AKS cluster v1.27.3, we followed the creation of Prometheus and Grafana using the istio v1.18.2 provided sample addons CRD and used this document to expose these apps over the ingress gateway.
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.23/samples/addons/prometheus.yaml

Exposing the services using document
The endpoint URLs are accessible for Prometheus and grafana, But the dashboards for all workloads are not visible. So whether the istio bundled these sample addons are only for istio component monitoring alone or can we use same instance to monitor other AKS applications as well? What we are expecting is Prometheus and grafana created from the istio sample addons should be extended to monitor other workloads in the cluster with Grafana dashboards as well.
